# How can I give an interval for a react application

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I am using react with antd framework. I have created a form and handling the submit:

My `forms.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, notification } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';

class CustomForm extends React.Component {

    handleFormSubmit  = (event, requestType, articleId) => {
        const title = event.target.elements.title.value;
        const content = event.target.elements.content.value;

 notification.open({

        message: 'Success',
    description:
    'Your Response is submitted',
            onClick: () => {
              console.log('Notification Clicked!');
    },
    onCancel: () => {
                
   }
});
         
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        switch (requestType) {
            case 'post':
                return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/', {
                    title:title,
                    content:content
                }
                )
                .then (res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
            case 'put':
                return axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/${articleId}/`, {
                    title:title,
                    content:content
                })
                .then (res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Form onSubmitCapture={(event) => this.handleFormSubmit(event, this.props.requestType, this.props.articleId)} >
                    <Form.Item label="Title">
                    <Input name='title' placeholder="Input some title" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item label="Content">
                    <Input name='content' placeholder="Input some content" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType='submit' >{this.props.btntext}</Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default CustomForm;
```

Using this I can get input from the user and show a success notification. But I want to reload my page after 5 seconds when I get the notification when I try to use this code `window.location.reload(true)`  in my `handleFormSubmit` it is not allowing the notification to take place.

Comment: where do you want to reload the page?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá I want to reload the page when the form is submitted after  5 seconds when the notification is displayed

Comment: `setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(true), 5000);` Try using this.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Thanks, It works perfectly.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá I have a suggestion for you

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá you can post your answer in the answer box below for users who take a look at this question

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá can You please post your answer in the answer section

Comment: below the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(true), 5000);` this code